# Python I/O error: How do I fix this program for file paths with whitespace?

Tags: python, io, whitespace, filepath

When running the codes.

```
file_path = raw_input("Drag the text file here: ")
file_path = file_path.strip()
file_handle = open(file_path, 'r')
for line in file_handle:
    print line
```

Output:

```
Drag the text file here: /Users/user_name/Desktop/white\ space/text.txt 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "desktop/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    file_handle = open(file_path, 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/user_name/Desktop/white\\ space/text.txt'
```

The program runs fine for any pathname without whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate fix would be removing the escaped `'\\'` characters, `file_path.strip().replace('\\', '')`

This should return `/Users/user_name/Desktop/white space/text.txt` which is a valid path for you to use.

Look into [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) for ways to handle pathnames.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that some characters can't be un-escaped simply by erasing the `\`. But since those characters are unlikely to be part of a filename, this might work.

Comment: @MarkRansom, you're most correct. I should have emphasized _immediate_ in my response.